# Codenameone BrowserComponent.setProperty giving NullPointerException

Tags: codenameone

Until today, my code has been working great. However, I've just started getting NPE when using the Crisp CN1lib. It turns out that BrowserComponent.setProperty() is the culprit. Here is my stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.setBrowserProperty(JavaSEPort.java:11340)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent.setProperty(BrowserComponent.java:607)
```

Looks like the JavaSEPort.setBrowserProperty() is causing it. Github shows the code was edited 2 days ago so maybe something broke.

My code is pretty basic:

```
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

        addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if(err.getError() != null) {
                Log.e(err.getError());
            }
            Log.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
        });        
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }

        BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
        browser.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onLoad, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            }
        });
        browser.setProperty("UseWideViewPort", true);
        browser.setProperty("LoadWithOverviewMode", true);
        browser.setProperty("DatabaseEnabled", true);
        browser.setProperty("BuiltInZoomControls", true);
        browser.setProperty("DisplayZoomControls", false);
        browser.setProperty("WebContentsDebuggingEnabled", true);
        browser.setFireCallbacksOnEdt(true);
        browser.setURL("https://www.instagram.com/brianabette/");

        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BorderLayout());
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Any pointers? Bug maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just made some performance improvements to BrowserComponent.  Looks like we missed a spot here, so there is a regression.  It is already [fixed in Git](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/c300fe1d336714c4f8291e2dc54a7beffe566571) and will be included in the next update next Friday.